# mysql dump copy new and changed data to DB

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I have a DB which is 60 GB and I have a live DB which is 13 GB , now on the live DB there are some new entries and updated entries too. Consider 13GB DB has same initial data which 60 GB has with some rows updated and last few entries are completely new. No I want to copy that 13 GB to 60 GB. I have the dump but the insert commands and when I try to import it, it shows me the foreign key constrained error and says it cannot delete or update. So I need a query for MySQL import so that it will copy the new data and update the new if any, and also the dump file is regular dump file with create, insert all those and it is not possible to change anything inside it :(

Comment: I have done my research and I am not sure if insert on dupllicate key update or ignore  is good idea?

Comment: Have no clear answer, but I would create two databases and than merge with some mysql database diff tools. I saw some tools that will compare not only schema, but data also. People say Toad for MySQL can do this.

Comment: @FAngel I have the Navicat full version, does it have that functionality?

Comment: Navicat - have no idea what is this. Check its manual. Toad is free, as I know and nothing stops you from trying it. [SQLDiff](http://sqldiff.en.softonic.com/) has required feature for sure. They should also have trial version.

Comment: NAvicat is cool and looks like I just managed to test it with small data and it worked, my only concern is time out issues. Its huge and are you sure TOAD can can handle 7-8 hours od time without going idle and being getting disconnected. if any of you know Navicat?

Answer (score 0):

If disk space isn't an issue here's how I would do it:

1. Take the database offline
2. If the original dasebase is called stuff, create a new database named stuff_extra
3. Load the 13 GB dump onto stuff_extra. You'll now have two databases that are identical on schema but differs in some of the data
4. For each table in stuff

   1. Delete all rows in stuff.table that are also in stuff_extra.table. You could just delete the rows that have changed but I think this is as fast. Use [`multi table delete`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html)
   2. Insert all rows in stuff_extra.table into stuff.table. Use [`insert select`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html)

You will now have all rows from stuff_extra in stuff. And all data that was updated has been updated (or really deleted and inserted).

Comment: I think I am completely looking for some thing else here. I have a 60GB data which is old and now I have 13 GB data which is live and both have same structure, in 13 GB initial rows are same as 60 GB but it latest entries are new . 13 GB is missing data in between. so I want to copy new and latest updates of 13 GB to 60 GB data which I will make it live.